# How to customize Recharts Pie Chart?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, charts, graphics, recharts

I have a pie chart that i want to show two things, the *store name* and the *percentage*. Currently, my chart looks like this
[image]

In the outer label, the *Loja* part, how can I change the font color to be just one color?
The inner label, the percentage, how can I move the label to the larger part of the slice, so it will have more space to show the number?

### My Chart Code

```
<ResponsiveContainer width="100%" height="100%">
  <PieChart margin={{ right: 10, left: 10 }}>
    <Pie
      data={chartData}
      dataKey="value"
      nameKey="name"
      outerRadius={90}
      label={(entry) => entry.name}
      cx="50%"
      cy="50%"
    >
      <LabelList dataKey="showValue" position="insideRight"/>
      {chartData.map((entry, index) => (
        <Cell
          key={`cell-${index}`}
          fill={`rgba(131, 54, 235, ${100 - index * 6}%)`}
          fontWeight={300}
        />
      ))}
    </Pie>
  </PieChart>
</ResponsiveContainer>
```

Comment: see if [this](https://recharts.org/en-US/examples/PieChartWithCustomizedLabel) helps

Comment: I tried it, but i would have to put everything together, like 'Loja 01 - 50%', and there's no space for it.

Comment: @JoséCarlos are you saying like you want to try something like this? 
https://codesandbox.io/s/pie-chart-with-customized-label-forked-g32vr6

Comment: @Ravikumar Exactly that, thank you!